# How to make a multiline alias in Bash?

Tags: bash, alias, function

I want to make an alias for a multiline ​command to call it faster then *copying-pasting-executing* it from a text file each time.

An example for such command is this *execute-a-remote-updater* command:

```
(
cd "${program_to_update_dir}"
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/USER/PROJECT/BRANCH/update.sh
source update.sh
rm update.sh
)
```

A couple of years ago I have learned that multiline commands' aliases are impossible due to Bash design limitations but perhaps since then the program has been changed and now it is possible.

---

I think that if it is still impossible, perhaps I could make a function with that code, export it to all shell sessions (although I rarely work with any subsessions and I don't  even recall when I last did that), and then call it somehow.

Should it be enough and secure to just wrap it in an `export`ed and *named function* in say `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` and then call it whenever I need to?

Comment: I would suggest that you won't find any difference in speed between writing a bash script, stored in a file in your `$PATH` and calling that vs writing those lines in an alias and calling that.  Bonus 1: your script will be so much easier to comment and maintain.  Bonus 2: your .bashrc will be so much easier to maintain.  Aliases have their uses, but for anything above a certain **very minimal** complication level, I would use a script.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's not impossible at all.

```
alias thing='(
cd "${program_to_update_dir}"
wget "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/USER/PROJECT/BRANCH/update.sh"
source update.sh
rm update.sh
)'
```

or,

```
alias thing='( cd "${program_to_update_dir}"; wget "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/USER/PROJECT/BRANCH/update.sh"; source update.sh; rm update.sh )'
```

The thing with aliases is that quoting may be tricky to get right as they are *text strings*, and that they are better suited for *really short* things, like

```
alias ls='ls -F'
```

In almost every other instance, you want a shell function instead:

```bsh
thing () (
    cd "${program_to_update_dir}"
    wget 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/USER/PROJECT/BRANCH/update.sh'
    source update.sh
    rm update.sh
)
```

Or, corrected to not use the `update.sh` name in the current directory (it may be taken by an unrelated file) and to only run `wget` if the `cd` succeeded, and slightly streamlined for the `bash` shell,

```bsh
thing () (
    cd "$program_to_update_dir" &&
    source <( wget --quiet -O - 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/USER/PROJECT/BRANCH/update.sh' )
)
```

(Note that you may want to run the `update.sh` script using `bash` instead of sourcing it, or pipe it to `bash -s`, or use whatever interpreter its `#!`-line uses.  The fact that you're using `source` on it is confusing as you're also running it in a subshell. The effect on the environment of running the script with `source`, which is usually why one wants to `source` a script, is lost when the subshell terminates.)

Shell functions may be define in the same initialization file that you define aliases in, and they are used in the same way as aliases, but are more versatile (can take arguments etc.)

The `bash` manual contains the statement

> For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.

Comment: Hello ! I understand your point that it's not impossible at all (as a one long line with field separations), but what if one wants to put several line between the double quote marks? Then, as far as I can recall it is impossible. About `corrected` --- I personally don't like the sugar syntax you have used, I personally find it confusing --- I never had trouble with the syntax I used...

Comment: My impression is in most cases like this an asker is not aware that any alias in Bash works by replacing some *string* with some *string*. There is no logic, just simple text replacement. Realizing this helped me a lot in understanding the concept.

Comment: @timesharer See updated answer (the start of it).  Also note that your code potentially overwrites a file called `update.sh` in the current directory, and that it runs the `update.sh` script regardless of whether the `cd` was successful, possibly leading to data loss.

Comment: Yes, nice, I should read it carefully again. Thanks,

Comment: Okay I have re-read the answer, again thanks ; what if I "really hate" the `<(...)` syntax? Perhaps I should ask another question after adding `&&` to `cd` and then I am still with the overriding problem that `<(...)` fixes, right? I don't know how to phrase this question... I understnad `curl -O -` downloads to Bash stdout but then how should I handle the data (again, if I don't want the `<(...)` syntax)?

Comment: @timesharer You could probably use `wget -O - 'URL' | bash -s`, depending on what that `update.sh` script does (would not work if it's interactive). Or, you could use `tmpname=$(mktemp); wget -O "$tmpname" 'URL'; bash "$tmpname"; rm -f "$tmpname"`.