# Downloading a file with a trivial name without overriding a possible existing file with the same name

Tags: bash, files, stdout, command-substitution, download

In CentOS with Bash I download a file with a very trivial file name, `install.sh`.

Although extremely unlikely in my scenario, this could still, in theory, overwrite some existing file with the same name.

How would you solve this problem?

---

If I understood correctly, [one way to deal with this is](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/641179/462635):

```
cd DOWNLOADS &&
source <( wget --quiet -O - 'URL/install.sh' )
```

But as a non professional sysadmin I seek a more "basic" or "simple" way because I am having hard time working with the `<(...)` syntax, let along with downloading to stdout with various options.

I was thinking about:

- Download a file with a randomly created long file name
- Do action with the file (such as `cp` and `mv` to change name)
- delete the downloaded file

Perhaps something like this pseudocode:

```
random_name=(wget -O kjghfkjdhsgkj.sh URL) # How to create random name by the computer?
destination=(cp "${random_name}" DESTINATION)
mv "${destination}" NEW_DESTINATION
rm "${random_name}"
```

Comment: Why would you want to move the randomly named file to a known name? Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of having the randomly generated name in the first place? Just download the script to a random filename, [like I mentioned to you before](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/641177/how-to-make-a-multiline-alias-in-bash#comment1202121_641179), and then run that script.

Comment: I thought that while the file is randomly-named, I could run some test to check if there is already a file with the known name and if not, store it as with the known name. But I know figure that I could make the test before downloading and only if there is no file with the original known name in the download destination --- then download.

Comment: I have edited the title to not be "XY problem" reflective.

Comment: "Make a test before downloading" gives you [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use). This is why we should use `mktemp`, it is designed to solve such problems.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks, I never came across this concept before.

Comment: Please share your opinion about the pseudocode I wanted to use --- it's easy for me understand but I lack computer-made-randomness there.

Answer (score 2):

`mktemp` is exactly here to let us create a file with a "semi-random" templated filename. See `man mktemp`; and for cleaning part, see `trap`.

Comment: Randomly-but-not-by-a-computer (in my case, by a human) is "semi-random"?

Comment: @timesharer For bigger projects consider `mktemp -d`. It creates a temporary directory, initially empty, so you can use fixed and meaningful names inside. Its your job to make them not to collide with one another, but they won't collide with anything external. Cleaning is trivial: you remove the entire directory.